# Is it OK to turn your SO question/answer into a blog post, and link to it?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220309) on SO, which I ended up answering myself after a journey of discovery into the world of git and bash. The info I gathered seemed good content to finally write my first [blog post](http://blog.codefarm.co.nz/) - which I'm sure is cool - but is it cool to then add a link from your question or answers to that blog post?

I think yes as long as you don't 'take away' from SO, the question/answers should retain all the necessary info. But the 'article' style of a blog post allows for a better formatted read - rather than the somewhat random answers/comments to a question on SO - and in this case feels like a better way to package the info. Apart from the excuse for a first blog post :)

Comment: All great answers below, so will mark as answer the one with most votes. But thanks all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure. I don't see anything wrong with that.

If you have an interesting story to tell "behind the scenes" of a Stack Overflow thread, why not tell the story?

Stack Overflow is not designed to get overly discussion-y or ramble-y. If you have more to say, stick it in a blog post.

Comment: +1 agreed. How about 'rambly'? http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rambly

Comment: Thanks for the link. If the word is not a Sniglet (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sniglets) or doesn't come up in Google's "define: <word>" search, I don't know about it. I guess I should include the "Urban Dictionary" as a *source authority* <grin>.

Answer (score 6):

Technically SO content is released under a Creative Commons license such that if you attribute the source and link back to it on SO, you can write a blog post and link to *anyone's* question or answer.

If it's something you've written I'm sure you can just write your own blog post on the same subject using the same text (you've written) with no issues whatsoever since you may have granted SO a license to reproduce that content under it's terms of use but it's not an exclusive license, meaning if you choose to write the exact same thing somewhere else, it doesn't fall automatically under the SO "umbrella".

Comment: This is how I understood the license too, but I wasn't 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

If the blog is relevant to the question then it is definitely acceptable. Any sources, whether they're blogs, technical references, or anything else are appropriate for linking. Though if you start linking to it when supplying answers that are just *vaguely* related, you may find yourself getting down voted for shameless plugs.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's definitely not cool is writing a blog post about something, then making a question about it and answering yourself, with a link to your blog post in the question/answer.

But I think in your case that's fine.  You're not doing something with the same intent.  I've seen people try to use SO just to get page visits on their site.  Definitely not cool.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that's fine.  It's even cooler to link from your blog post back to SO, saying where you got the idea for the post.   (Even though, if I understand correctly, you aren't absolutely *required* to do so for SO content that *you* create.  Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.)